# Get shipping rates from quote

Tags: magento2, shipping, table-rates

I created an API endpoint to use for shipping rate estimates.

However it only works for flat rates, neither free shipping, nor table rates show up.

I've added a product to the cart, and using the same country and zipcode, all rates show correctly.

My endpoint:

```
 public function getShippingEstimateCEP($sku, $qty, $cep)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        $out = 'api GET: $sku ' . $sku . $cep;
        if($product->isSaleable())  {
            $store=$this->storeManager->getStore();
            $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
            $quote->setStoreId($this->getStoreId());
            $quote->setWebsiteId($this->getWebsiteId());
            $quote->setStore($store);

            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('BR');
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setPostcode($cep);
            $quote->setIsMultiShipping(false);    

            $quote->addProduct($product);
            $quote->collectTotals();
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
            $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

            foreach ($rates as $rate)
            {
                $out .= '[' . $rate->getPrice() . '||'.  $rate->getMethod() . '||'. $rate->getMethodTitle() . ']';
            }
        }

        return $out ;
    }
```

Comment: $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
     $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
     $address->collectShippingRates();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a quote and getting an estimate in a REST API enpoint didn't work without hardcoding an old cart id, emptying it, then reusing it to get the estimates.

In the end I found it was better to use Magento's own API to:

- Create a cart: POST rest/default/V1/guest-carts
- Add items to cart: POST rest/default/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items
- Get estimates: POST rest/default/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/estimate-shipping-methods

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $api = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement');       
    $listShipping = $api->estimateByExtendedAddress($quote->getId(), $quote->getShippingAddress());
```

To use this code, you need to save your quote first. Or you can look at the calculation in the ShippingMethodManagement for more detail.

Comment: I've tried copying ShippingMethodManagement  model to my plugin and using it there, but it doesn't work. But if I edit the core ShippingMethodManagement, empty the current cart, add the product and address, don't save, then calculate the shipping, it works. But only by editing the `vendor/magento/.../ShippingMethodManagement `.

Comment: I tried this and it works, however only for existing carts. So if there is no cart created in the session, it doesn't work. I could hardcode an old cart id, empty it then add products and calculate, but that's crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

<s>I think you are missing getShippingAddress() in the collectTotals()</s>

```
 public function getShippingEstimateCEP($sku, $qty, $cep)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        $out = 'api GET: $sku ' . $sku . $cep;
        if($product->isSaleable())  {
            $store=$this->storeManager->getStore();
            $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
            $quote->setStoreId($this->getStoreId());
            $quote->setWebsiteId($this->getWebsiteId());
            $quote->setStore($store);

            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('BR');
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setPostcode($cep);
            $quote->setIsMultiShipping(false);    

            $quote->addProduct($product);
            $quote->collectTotals();
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
            $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();

            foreach ($rates as $rate)
            {
                $out .= '[' . $rate->getPrice() . '||'.  $rate->getMethod() . '||'. $rate->getMethodTitle() . ']';
            }
        }

        return $out ;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `Invalid method: ["Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address","collectTotals"]`

Comment: @localhost try updated answer

Comment: Doesn't add the other methods. I directly edited the core ShippingMethodManagement.php file and used the quote instead of the cart and it failed just the same. Maybe the way the quote is created is wrong or missing something?